# I want to modify IP_ADDRESS table in given form

Tags: sql

My table is,

```
MACHINE              IP_ADDRESS
-------------------- ------------
1                    10.0.12.43
2                    10.10.86.43
3                    34.10.86.43
```

I want to modify IP_ADDRESS column in the following form,

```
MACHINE              IP_ADDRESS
-------------------- ------------
1                    10012.43
2                    101086.43
3                    341086.43
```

how can I modify this using sql query

Comment: here,Machine and ip_address are two different columns

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Please type out your requirements out as a sentence in English. Do you want to "remove all dots from a varchar except the last"?

Comment: I want answer for either oracle or sql

Comment: @CodeCaster,YES.I want to remove all dots insted last one

Comment: @userA, you know that the result value cannot be longer used as key? 10012.43 can be 10.0.12.43 or 100.1.2.43;  101086.43 can be  10.10.86.43 or 101.0.86.43 or 10.108.6.43.

Comment: @lexx9999 I am not getting u,If you are talking about result table then I have written this as a example.I am not using this result table for other purpose...lets take another example...

Comment: @lexx9999, suppose I want to write one big amount one lakh fifty thousand, so in english I will write this number as, 1,50,000.00.In this case, I want to remove all (,) and I want to modify this number as 150000.00.I hope you got my point..

Comment: @lexx9999 consider same amount,but I have written this as 1.50.000.00. Here in this case I want to modify this data as 150000.00. i.e I want to remove all 2 dots(.) from left side and keep last dot as it is.

Comment: @userA, given "1,50,000.00" you should not store it as string, then removal is just a matter of formatting. 
Given "1.50.000.00" is supposed to be a number the input should be checked and this should never get into a database. I just wanted to point out that you are somehow in danger.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MySQL` you could use:

```
SELECT *,
   CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(IP_ADDRESS,'.', 3),'.','')
          ,'.',SUBSTRING_INDEX(IP_ADDRESS,'.', -1)) AS result
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33753/10/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ MACHINE  ║ IP_ADDRESS   ║  result   ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╣
║       1  ║ 10.0.12.43   ║  10012.43 ║
║       2  ║ 10.10.86.43  ║ 101086.43 ║
║       3  ║ 34.10.86.43  ║ 341086.43 ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

---

Another funny way to get it using only basic string operations:

```
SELECT *,
 CONCAT(
   LEFT(IP_ADDRESS, LENGTH(IP_ADDRESS) - 
                    LENGTH(TRIM(RIGHT(REPLACE(IP_ADDRESS, '.', 
                           REPEAT(' ',LENGTH(IP_ADDRESS)))
                          ,LENGTH(IP_ADDRESS))))-1) 
    ,'.',       
   TRIM(RIGHT(REPLACE(IP_ADDRESS, '.', REPEAT(' ',LENGTH(IP_ADDRESS)))
        ,LENGTH(IP_ADDRESS)))
  ) AS result
FROM tab
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33753/33/0)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks @lad2025,will u plz describe this query in brief ?